# "expected primary-expression before '.' token" in debug code

Tags: arduino-uno, debugging, software, debug

I'm making some code for school, and is adding debug code to it. When compiling, I get the error as written in the title. This is the code in question:

```
#define DEBUG 1

#ifdef DEBUG
#define Serial.println(x) DEBUG_PRINT(x)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(x)
#endif
```

And the code in my void setup, which has Serial.begin:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
Serial.begin(9600);
DEBUG_PRINT("Asteroid");
#endif
```

What am I getting wrong? I get the feeling it's my define text, but I'm unsure.

Thank you for your time
Gaarden

Comment: Macros cannot contain a `.`. Thus you cannot define a macro `Serial.println(x)`. You probably wanted to define it the other way around anyway.

`#define DEBUG_PRINT(x) Serial.println(x)`

Comment: I switched them around, per Kwasmich's comment. Now the error message is "expected ';' before 'Serial'"

Comment: Somewhere in your code (not shown above) you have a DEBUG_PRINT statement where in the line before that you have skipped the `;`

Comment: Didn't know it would give me an error message on that line if a line further down had a problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Kwasmich You posted an answer as a comment. Please make a proper answer. Then you will get rep for it, and Stack Exchange will consider the question answered. Win win!

Comment: @NickGammon, I see this as typographic error (and I will downvote an answer to this question). I voted to close

Comment: @Juraj Typographical errors are errors too.  Besides, this isn't a typographical error. A typographical error would be `Serial.print1n()`. This is a lack of understanding of how macros work and should be formed on the part of the OP and deserves aiding the OP in improving their understanding.

Answer (score 2):

In short: you have your macro backwards.

Macros are not formed as "Take this set of commands and call it X" but "Make this macro X and have it equate to this set of commands".

Where you have:

```
#define Serial.println(x) DEBUG_PRINT(x)
```

it should instead read:

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT(x) Serial.println(x)
```

When you call it, because the macro doesn't contain a semi-colon in it, you need to specify the semi-colon as if you were calling a function:

```
DEBUG_PRINT("Aardvark");
```

You can omit the semi-colon only if you have a semi-colon in your macro:

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT(x) Serial.println(x);
```

and then:

```
DEBUG_PRINT("Aardvark")
```

By doing it that way your "empty" macro now does become truly empty when used.  Without the semi-colon in the macro you would have to use:

```
DEBUG_PRINT("Aardvark");
```

Which for the empty variant would end up as:

```
;
```

Not always desirable, and can cause some problems.

So by adding the semi-colon into the macro you can omit it from the usage of the macro, and your empty variant now becomes:

Answer (score 1):

You defined the pre-processor macro the wrong way around.
Think it is like an assign statement. You come up with a name and assign something to it.

`#define SHORT_NAME(ARG) some_real_function_that_has_an_awkward_long_name(ARG)`

See the manual of your favourite compiler [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) for reference.
It is always a good idea to do that when using features you haven't used before. Sometimes it can be enlighting.